# Extract meta infromation from URL in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to extract the meta-information(title, image) from URL and display it like facebook. I have read some documents and written this code. Since i am new in angular. I dont get it where i am doing wrong

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope,$http){      
    $http.get('www.socialorra.com').
    success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $scope.url=$(data).filter('meta[name=title]').attr("content");  
    }).
    error(function(data,status,headers,config){

    }); 
}
```

Comment: is your javascript in the same domain as `www.socialorra.com`? If not you are violating the same-origin policy which will not let you get data from another domain (unless it uses cors). You will need to do the same thing facebook and other sites do, let a server side script scrape the page and return it

Comment: no its on another domain but this is just an example. I want to create link preview of any url just like facebook.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, it won't work if your website isn't on the same domain as the URL that you are trying to extract.

That's because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). If you are trying to extract data from FB, Google, Quora or whatever site that isn't on your domain nor uses CORS, you should handle it on the backend.